# Netbeans (7.4): Is there a way to highlight TODO's?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, todo

I have switched from Eclipse to Netbeans. Eclipse has a way too highlighting TODO's in Java comments like:

```
public void test(String str) {
  // TODO: check if str is null!
  ...
  ...
}
```

In Eclipse I could change the editor configuration so that the TODO was printed bold or in another color. Is there a way to set that up in Netbeans?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, right now there is no way to separate highlighting for TODO. You can only change the highlighting for comments. But that's not what you want.

In NB 7.4 there is a new way to control tasks (especially bug tasks). You can connect NB with a bug tracking tool like Bugzilla or JIRA.

Look here for this new feature: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB74#Tasks_window

Answer (score 67):

There's a helpful Netbeans feature that has been renamed to *Action items* in version 7.4 and has formerly been known as *Todo Tasks*. To show occurences of keywords in comments like `TODO` or `FIX` in a separate list go to *Window/Action Items*. The listed keywords can be configured in *Tools/Options/Miscellaneous/Action Items*.

Comment: Nice answer and good to know, but my question was not for a list of `TODO`s items. My question was about highlighting `TODO`s directly in the source code view. So still rawdog's answer is the accepted answer ...

Comment: In version 8.2 the keywords are in Tools/Options/Team/Action Items

Comment: If only I could give you more upvotes my friend! Amazing answer. @Deve

Comment: While editing PHP files it does not get highlighted... using NetBeans 11.0.

Answer (score 17):

Following Deve's answer, in Netbeans 8 things changed a little bit.

In version 8, it is in `Tools/Options/Team/Action Items`

More info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsENrzwsiOw&hd=1

Comment: And in the OS X version of NetBeans this is **NetBeans/Preferences/Team/Action Items**

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin "Editor TODO Highlighting", which highlights TODO's in JavaDoc syntax.

But it is **only available in nightly** builds of netbeans through plugin portal. [Here's the issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247416).

Comment: The link inside the issue is broken :(

Comment: There is a new link to download from the Dropbox, just scroll down

Comment: Thank you. It works with NetBeans 11.0, but it only highlights `/** @TODO */`. It does not highlight `// TODO`...

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin works that way. It ignores `// TODO` etc. You need to use doc block syntax like in [Cody Maust answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195419/5444623).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve something close in Netbeans 8.0 (I can't speak for 7.4)..

You will need to use the Javadoc syntax:

```
/** @TODO something */
```

This isn't the most desirable workaround, but it is sufficient for me.

Comment: The Action Items window in NetBeans 8.0 not only has a dedicated TODO filter, it also allows for fine-tuning, e.g., you can use an additional keyword filter to limit the TODO display only to items where the description contains the word "remove"..

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans 8.2 its called **Action Items** and you can find it in **Window tab > Action items.**
Maybe this link can be useful: http://www-acad.sheridanc.on.ca/~jollymor/prog24178/nbActionItems.html

**Add custom keywords (DOTO instead of TODO):** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsENrzwsiOw

Comment: this answer is the same as earlier answers. Even the youtube link is the same as dazito posted

Answer (score 0):

I have not found out yet, if it's possible to highlight a code line that contains "todo" in Apache NetBeans Version 17
But in Version 17 you can go to "Windows->Action Items" and a window will pop up with all todos it can find in the current file.
When i opened it the first time it took a minute to index all.
Hope this helps.